# Find each column in a table in my java 8 stream

Tags: java, java-stream, htmlunit

I am using `HtmlUnit` to get an `HtmlTable`. I am trying to get a List of cells of each column.

So far, in the code I've tried I can find the first column. How can I iterate through each column and run some code in them?

I'd like to make sure they're all sorted alphabetically, but I just need to figure out where to place that code.

EDIT: I found my answer. I think I worded the question wrong. I needed to get each column and put them into their own collection. In the original example, I showed only column1. But I need EACH column (based upon how many cells are in each row). Below is some code that worked. But it may be able to be optimized better.

```
HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/myurl");

    HtmlTable myTable = htmlPage.getHtmlElementById("mytable");

    // find the number of columns by grabbing the first row and returning the number
    // of cells within the first row
    int numberOfColumns = myTable.getRows().stream().map(row -> row.getCells()).findFirst().get()
            .size();

    // initialize columns
    List<List<String>> columns = new ArrayList<List<String>>(numberOfColumns);

    // initialize new arraylists for each column based upon the number of columns
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfColumns; i++)
        columns.add(new ArrayList<>());

    // iterate through each column
    for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numberOfColumns; columnIndex++) {

        // iterate through each row
        for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < myTable.getRows().size(); rowIndex++) {

            String asText = myTable.getCellAt(rowIndex, columnIndex).asText();
            columns.get(columnIndex).add(asText);
        }
    }

    //iterate through the columns and do stuff!
    columns.forEach(a -> {
        //do stuff to the column such as verify it was sorted, or sort it yourself etc
        System.out.println("column" + a.toString());
        a.forEach(b -> {
            //do stuff 
            LOG.info(b);
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just do this as part of your join as single stream:

```
webClient.getPage("http://localhost:8080/myUrl")
         .getHtmlElementById("myTable")
         .getRows()
         .stream()
         .map(row -> row.getCells().stream().findFirst().get().asText())
         .sort((o1, o2) -> o1.compareTo(o2)) // make alphabetical
         .collect(Collectors.joining("|"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can collect it to a `List` of `List`'s:

```
List<List<HtmlTableCell>> columns = 
                          myTable.getRows()
                                 .stream()
                                 .map(row -> row.getCells()
                                                .stream()
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList())
                                 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

And then when you need to log:

```
LOG.info(columns.stream()
                .flatMap(List::stream)                    
                .map(m -> m.asText())
                .sorted()         //Sort the list
                .collect(Collectors.joining("|")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the table as a list of lists (`List<List<HtmlTableCell>>`) this will do it

```
List<List<HtmlTableCell>> table = myTable.getRows().stream()
        .map(row -> row.getCells().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Or, if you won't need the `List` later, you can skip collecting to list and execute your code instead

```
List<List<HtmlTableCell>> table = myTable.getRows().stream()
        .map(row -> row.getCells().stream().collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEachOrdered(cellList -> System.out.println(cellList));
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want a `List<HtmlTableCell>` representing the data in a given column of your html table you need to use [getCellAt](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlTable.html#getCellAt-int-int-) which takes a row index and column index.

```
IntStream.range(0, numberOfColumns)
         .mapToObj(colIndex -> IntStream.range(0, numberOfRows)
             .mapToObj(rowIndex -> myTable.getCellAt(rowIndex, colIndex)).collect(toList())) 
         .collect(toList());
```

where `numberOfColumns` should be replaced with the number of columns in your HTML table and the `numberOfRows` should be replaced with the number of rows in your HTML table.

This will yield a `List<List<HtmlTableCell>>` where each `List<HtmlTableCell>` is all the cells for each column.

---

For completeness here is how you can sort each `List<HtmlTableCell>` i.e. each columns data.

```
List<List<HtmlTableCell>> result = 
     IntStream.range(0, numberOfColumns)
              .mapToObj(colIndex -> IntStream.range(0, numberOfRows)
                     .mapToObj(rowIndex -> myTable.getCellAt(rowIndex, colIndex))
                     .sorted(Comparator.comparing(HtmlTableCell::asText))
                     .collect(toList())) 
              .collect(toList());
```

and log it:

```
// concatenate each cell data of each column separated by a pipe and then separate each column data by a line separator.
String joined = result.stream()
      .map(l -> l.stream().map(HtmlTableCell::asText).collect(Collectors.joining("|")))
      .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
// log it! 
LOG.info(joined);
```

Note that if all you're doing is logging then it's not worth collecting to an intermediate `List<List<HtmlTableCell>>` rather, you can get the result you require as:

```
 String joined = IntStream.range(0, numberOfColumns)
                          .mapToObj(colIndex -> IntStream.range(0, numberOfRows)
                                .mapToObj(rowIndex -> myTable.getCellAt(rowIndex, colIndex).asText())
                                .sorted()
                                .collect(Collectors.joining("|")))
                        .collect(Collectors.joining(System.lineSeparator()));
LOG.info(joined);
```